# How to create html links based on a text document of inputs

Tags: html, bash, text

Alright so basically I've got a txt of inputs: e.g,

```
fde
fefe
4fd
f3faf
```

I would like to take all of the inputs in the text document and have a bash script which outputs HTML links, e.g.

```
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/fde/'>https://wwww.example.com/fde/</a>
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/fefe/'>https://wwww.example.com/fefe/</a>
```

So for each file of lines of characters, an html with hyperlinks on each line is expected. Thank you much if you can help. I'm attempting to do this in bash/linux terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is named `test.txt`, you can solve it the following way:

```
cat test.txt | while read string; do echo "<a href='https://wwww.example.com/$string'>https://wwww.example.com/$string</a>"; done
```

The output would be:

```html
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/fde'>https://wwww.example.com/fde</a>
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/fefe'>https://wwww.example.com/fefe</a>
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/4fd'>https://wwww.example.com/4fd</a>
<a href='https://wwww.example.com/f3faf'>https://wwww.example.com/f3faf</a>
```

You can as well create a bash script that expects a file location to be passed:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[[ -z $1 || ! -f $1 ]] && echo "File not found." && exit 1

cat $1 | \
    while read string; do
        echo "<a href='https://wwww.example.com/$string'>https://wwww.example.com/$string</a>"
    done
```

Note that this solution does not escape the strings, i.e. if your strings contain HTML entities like `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` or `'`, you may need to escape them.

Comment: Okay so this is very helpful. If I remembered anything about bash I could probably come to the right solutions, but instead I must ask directly for more of your philanthropy. Oops didn't mean to hit enter... I was going to ask how I can a) have this as a bash script I can run text files through and b) have the output be an htm file. Thanks.

Comment: Just added a script example. To redirect it into a different file, use [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). Basically `./script.sh > targetfile.html`. (Or use `>>` to append to an existing file.)

Comment: Eh. Actually I just added cat > file.htm to the end and thankfully it works. It's not everything, but at least it works.

I'm very glad you were so helpful. Thank you. I'd grant you some sort of karma if this weren't a throwaway acct.

Didn't see your quick response. Many thanks

Comment: You can still upvote and accept the answer. That's the Stack Overflow version of karma. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while read line
do
    echo "<a href='https://wwww.example.com/"$line"/'>https://wwww.example.com/"$line"/</a>"
done < "your-file-name"
```

Assuming this code is in a script file called script.sh, execute the following in the terminal:

```
chmod +x script.sh #to grant execute right
./script.sh #to launch the script
```

Comment: Thanks! This is another great answer.