# HTML script to convert a text string(s) into a specified hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink

My basic requirement is to convert given text anchors into hyperlinks,  using HTML or any browser side script. We use Windows10/IE/Edge, FYI.

Example : Given text

```
ABC
CDE
EFG
```

Required Output:

```
www.xyz.com/test/ABC
www.xyz.com/test/CDE
www.xyz.com/test/EFG
```

I have found a bash to hyperlink query here. My requirement is similar but need a browser based script

[How to create html links based on a text document of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527594/how-to-create-html-links-based-on-a-text-document-of-inputs)

Comment: HTML is not a programming language

Comment: How is this text provided for browser?

Comment: I'd like to copy paste in the a text box (in browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put text in `<textarea>` and read it's content using js/jQuery.

Create links dynamically in memory and later use where needed (I simply append to DOM)

```js
var urlBase = 'https://example.com';

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input').change(function () {
    var lines = $(this).val().split("\n"); // Split textarea content by new line
    var links = $('#links'); // Links container
    links.html(''); // Empty container content
    
    $.each(lines, function (i, line) {
      links.append($('<a>', {href: urlBase + '/' + line, text: line})); // Append new link element
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#links a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>

<div id="links"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the text input, split it at the new lines and create a string of the a's with teh desired hrefs. I am using a ul to display the results.

Note the advantage of creating a string that is then added to the DOM is that it affects the DOM only once - rather than on each loop of the append option. A small matter for when there is a small list, but if there are millions of lines to be appended - the constant DOM maniulation may cause issues if you use .append().

```js
function convertText(){
 var links= document.getElementById('textInput').value;
 var linksArr = links.split('\n');
 
 var linkStr = '';
linksArr.forEach(function(link){
  linkStr += '<li><a href="www.xyz.com/test/'+link+'">'+link+'</a></li>';
})

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = linkStr;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="textInput"></textarea>
<hr/>
<button type="button" onclick="convertText()">Convert text to links</button>

<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Comment: That was quick, Thank you.

But there is a challenge here. The code works perfect on edge but doesn't work on IE11. Also, is there a way we can make the text input box expandable?